# What is lft+rt button on XBox 360

Tags: xbox-360, need-for-speed-the-run

I am new to Xbox 360 (A week old!). I bought Need for speed: The Run. The starting of this game is an escape from the car. I pressed "B" button on the controller, to free him from the steering, but after this I am shown "Lft+rt" on the screen. I do not know what key is this or what combination of keys is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few abbreviations used for Xbox 360 buttons.  They are:

LB and RB - The left and right bumpers.  These are the buttons on the top of the controller that are closer to you.  They look and act like normal shoulder buttons.  On a PlayStation console, these would be L1 and R1.

LT and RT - The left and right triggers.  There are the buttons on the top of the controller that are farther away from you.  They look like the trigger of a gun (hence the name).  On a PlayStation console, these would be L2 and R2.

LS and RS - These refer to the left stick or right stick on the controller.  These double as buttons when you press them in.  On a PlayStation console, the buttons for those would be called L3 and R3.

I've never played the game you're referring to, but it could be referring to hitting both triggers, or pressing left on the stick and right trigger... or even left on the control pad (below the left stick) and right trigger.

Comment: Haven't played either, but I'm guessing it means Left on the stick + RT as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Powerlord. It was the LT and RT trigger buttons. I used them, and I could progress with the game.